# Require Login to View Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, security, login

Is there a way to require login before a user can see a Lightning Component in Salesforce Community?

Comment: put that component on community page which is only visible only after login?

Comment: After much pain tries, this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Not without code.  The "audience" filter in the community builder filters by profile, permission, location, and other criteria.  But not login session.

Instead, the component's controller must check for the user id.  Then the markup should use an aura:if to show/hide the whole component if they are a guest user or not.